# Viewpager Sliding Animation in RTL

Tags: android, right-to-left

I'm having a Viewpager with Tabs Holding Fragments, when the layout direction is RTL the order of tabs and fragments are reversed, however the direction of sliding animation of the fragments are still as in LTR, is there a way to reverse the sliding animation in case of RTL?

Comment: Imo, you have to handle it manually, there's no api which will do that for you out of the box. `if(isRtl()) -> show particular animation...`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing viewPager swipe direction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32443558/changing-viewpager-swipe-direction)

Answer (score 1):

I am using [RtlViewPager](https://github.com/diego-gomez-olvera/RtlViewPager) library from Duolingo for exactly these purposes (reverse fragment tabs order, change animation direction). It works like a charm for me.